# Algorithm to detect "brownian/random walk" movement in path in GPS path

Tags: algorithm, gps, openstreetmap

I am currently contributing to openstreetmap and when I import data I can often see this kind of cluster of points

[image: brownian movement]

They are due to the imprecision of GPS when static interferes with signal reception.  I would like to programmatically get rid of that problem, to replace those points by their centroid. How can I detect this pattern in a 
given a list of points?

[
   (x1, y1),
   (x2, y2),
   (x3, y3),
   (x4, y4),
   ...
   (xn, yn)
]

being able to detect a set of points that belongs to said "random walk" pattern, so that I can them replace them by the centroid of these points. My intuition tell me that this algorithm should take as parameter a threshold parameter in both the number of points and distance between two points after which we start to consider such a list of points as "random walk".

But as I think it's a common problem while doing GPS tracing, I hope that I've overlooked a state of the art algorithm to detect these.

Comment: It would help a lot if you have timestamps for each of those points. For example, if two points are 500 meters apart, and the time stamps are 10 seconds apart, that implies a speed of 50m/s or 180 km/hr. So you can be pretty sure that didn't actually happen.

Comment: @user3386109 , the points are espaced ~1 minutes each, and a first take on it show that all have a acceptable speed :( , I guess I could improve the data by sampling more often in which case I would be able to have "too high to be true speed", but in that case it will use too much my battery.

Comment: You can use gpsprune or gpsbabel to simplify your track, to remove duplicates and inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simple *ex post facto* trend analysis.  Maintain a moving average of expected path, where each reading is predicted to be an extension of the velocity of the preceding points, something like

```
new_vector = 0.2 * current_vector + 0.8 * old_vector
```

Do this in both directions (time-reversed for the second).

When you find a series of points that are seriously disconnected in both past and future, and don't seem to deviate much in position, then you've identified your static period.  The basic characteristics are consistent directional changes.

Does that get you moving toward a solution?

Comment: I need to make ex-post-facto trend analysis to see if i was moving toward the right solution or simply "random walking" ,  joke aside, it seems a good start, though I need to see what happen on "normal case" that deviate from "going straight" (like doing a 180 degree turn)

Comment: Correct.  with a normal turn, you'll have solid predictions both before and after that point; and the "aging" vector trends will have a smooth transition.  With a random walk, the second differences will vary ... well, randomly.